How to format the NFC message to make an Apple Wallet badge compatible with an ARD scanner?
I'm currently developing an access solution using NFC technology on Apple devices. With iOS 18, Apple has opened up access to NFC functionality, which allows me to create access badges that I then add to Apple Wallet. My aim is to use these badges via an ARD reader.
What I've managed to do:
Obtain the necessary certificates from Apple.
Create an .pkpass file.
Add this file to Apple Wallet without any problems.
My problem: I now want this badge to be recognized by an ARD reader. To do this, I need to write the NFC message associated with the badge correctly. However, I'm not sure what specific format or payload to use to ensure compatibility with ARD readers.
Technical details :
Reader used: Bi-technology model ISO 14443 A/B - ISO 18092 at 13.56 MHz and Bluetooth® Low Energy (BLE).
Compatibility: MIFARE® chips and ARD Mobile ID™ virtual badges on smartphones.
Questions :
NFC message format: Is there a specific format or scheme I need to follow to structure the NFC message so that it is recognized by the ARD scanner?
Recommended payload: What type of NFC payload (data to be encoded) is expected by the ARD reader for badge recognition?
ARD documentation: Are there any resources or documentation concerning NFC communication with ARD readers that you could recommend?
Examples or best practices: If anyone has already implemented a similar solution, code examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
What I've already tried:
Using different payload types in the .pkpass file, but without success for recognition by the ARD reader.
Consulted Apple documentation on Wallet and NFC passes, but no specific information on ARD compatibility.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Most NFC Tag emulation on phones emulates a Type4A NFC Tag and thus can be read using ISO 7816 but I don't know what AID they would be using.

You would need information from ARD, which they are unlikely to provide

@Paulw11 I tried to get some information from the ARD documents, but I still couldn't figure it out. I couldn't find any.

@Andrew Yes, you're right. I debugged a pkpass while testing it live with the macOS console, and I figured out that it can be read. However, I still have an issue with the NFC payload, in order to be properly interpreted and used as an access badge

As I said, you are unlikely to be able to find anything.  It could possibly be reverse engineered but most likely there are private keys involved that you won't have access to.  The whole point of an access control reader is to make it difficult for people to replicate credentials
